Moveit Trajectory execution failed after planning was successful
ROS2 HUMBLE
UBUNTU 22.4
After i run my launch file with movegroup, i add motion planning in rviz and whenever i try to plan and execute something, the execution fails and shows the following error:
[gzserver-1] [ERROR] [1732573974.848351362] [robot_controller]: Time between points 0 and 1 is not strictly increasing, it is 0.000000 and 0.000000 respectively
[move_group-7] [ERROR] [1732573974.848675409] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Goal was rejected by server
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1732573974.848679636] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: robot_controller started execution
[move_group-7] [WARN] [1732573974.848774091] [moveit.simple_controller_manager.follow_joint_trajectory_controller_handle]: Goal request rejected
[move_group-7] [ERROR] [1732573974.848715431] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Failed to send trajectory part 1 of 1 to controller robot_controller
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1732573974.848823434] [moveit_ros.trajectory_execution_manager]: Completed trajectory execution with status ABORTED ...
[move_group-7] [INFO] [1732573974.857176429] [moveit_move_group_default_capabilities.move_action_capability]: Solution found but controller failed during execution
[rviz2-8] [INFO] [1732573974.858184308] [move_group_interface]: Plan and Execute request aborted
[rviz2-8] [ERROR] [1732573974.859222081] [move_group_interface]: MoveGroupInterface::move() failed or timeout reached

the configuration files i am using are done by moveit setup assistant and the controller is supposed to be alright. I will show my launch file and controller configuration below.
Launch file:
def generate_launch_description():

    paused = LaunchConfiguration('paused', default='false')
    gazebo_gui = LaunchConfiguration('gazebo_gui', default='true')
    urdf_path_str = os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('robot_model'), 'urdf', 'mtr.urdf')
    use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time', default='true')

    install_dir = get_package_prefix('robot_model')
    gazebo_models_path = get_package_share_directory('robot_model')
    moveit_config_package_path = get_package_share_directory('robot_moveit_config')
    doc = xacro.parse(open(urdf_path_str))
    xacro.process_doc(doc)
    rps_param = {'robot_description': doc.toxml()}
    

    if 'GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH' in os.environ:
        os.environ['GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH'] =  os.environ['GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH'] + ':' + gazebo_models_path
    else:
        os.environ['GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH'] =  gazebo_models_path

    if 'GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH' in os.environ:
        os.environ['GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH'] = os.environ['GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH'] + ':' + install_dir + '/lib'
    else:
        os.environ['GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH'] = install_dir + '/lib'

    spawn_entity = Node(
            package= 'gazebo_ros',
            executable='spawn_entity.py',
            name='spawn_entity',
            output='screen',
            arguments=['-entity', 'robot', '-topic', '/robot_description'],
        )
    

        
    moveit_config = (MoveItConfigsBuilder(
                        robot_name = "robot",
                        package_name = 'robot_moveit_config')
                     .robot_description(file_path=moveit_config_package_path + '/config/robot.urdf.xacro')
                     .robot_description_semantic(file_path=moveit_config_package_path + '/config/robot.srdf')
                     .robot_description_kinematics(file_path=moveit_config_package_path +'/config/kinematics.yaml')
                     .joint_limits(file_path=moveit_config_package_path +"/config/joint_limits.yaml")
                     .trajectory_execution(file_path= moveit_config_package_path + '/config/moveit_controllers.yaml')
                     .planning_scene_monitor(publish_robot_description= True, publish_robot_description_semantic=True)
                     .planning_pipelines(pipelines =["ompl"])
                     .pilz_cartesian_limits(file_path= moveit_config_package_path + '/config/pilz_cartesian_limits.yaml')
                     .to_moveit_configs()
                     )
   
    load_robot_controller = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active', 'robot_controller'],
        output='screen',
    )

    load_joint_state_broadcaster = ExecuteProcess(
        cmd=['ros2', 'control', 'load_controller', '--set-state', 'active', 'joint_state_broadcaster'],
        output='screen',
    )



    return LaunchDescription([
        DeclareLaunchArgument('paused', default_value='false'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument('gazebo_gui', default_value='true'),
        DeclareLaunchArgument('use_sim_time', default_value='true'),
    
        # Launch Gazebo
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource([os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('gazebo_ros'),'launch', 'gazebo.launch.py') ]),
            launch_arguments={
                'verbose': 'true',
                'paused': LaunchConfiguration('paused'),
                'gazebo_gui': LaunchConfiguration('gazebo_gui'),
                'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
            }.items()
        ), 

        
        Node(
            package='robot_state_publisher',
            executable='robot_state_publisher',
            output='screen',
            parameters=[rps_param, {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}, {'publish_frequency': 100.0}]
        ),

       
        #Spawn the room
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['ros2', 'run', 'gazebo_ros', 'spawn_entity.py', '-entity', 'room', '-x', '0', '-y', '0.8475', '-z', '1.4', '-file',
                 os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('robot_simulation'), 'models', 'Scan_Room', 'model.sdf')],
            output='screen'
        ), 

        #Spawn the bed
        ExecuteProcess(
            cmd=['ros2', 'run', 'gazebo_ros', 'spawn_entity.py', '-entity', 'bed', '-z', '0.375', '-Y', '1.57', '-file', 
                 os.path.join(get_package_share_directory('robot_simulation'), 'models', 'PatientBedMultix', 'model.sdf')],
            output='screen'
        ), 

        # push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo at the origin, change x,y,z arguments to spawn in a different position 
        spawn_entity,

        #make sure of the order of the commands of the controllers 
        RegisterEventHandler(
            event_handler= OnProcessExit(
                target_action = spawn_entity,
                on_exit=[ load_robot_controller,
                        load_joint_state_broadcaster,
                        ]
            )
        ), 

        Node(
            package="moveit_ros_move_group",
            executable="move_group",
            name="move_group",
            output="screen",
            parameters=[
                moveit_config.to_dict(),
                {"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}
             
            ],
        ),
     
        Node(
            package='rviz2',
            executable='rviz2',
            name='rviz2', 
            output = 'screen',
            parameters=[{"use_sim_time": use_sim_time}],
        ),
  

    ])

controller configuration:
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters: 
    update_rate: 100 #Hz

    robot_controller: 
      type: joint_trajectory_controller/JointTrajectoryController

    joint_state_broadcaster: 
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster
      #state: active


robot_controller:
  ros__parameters: 
    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity
    joints:
      - RadTubePrismHorizontal
      - RadTubeLongitudinal
      - RadTubeLift
      - RadTubeRotVertical
      - RadTubeRotHorizontal
      - CollimatorRotA
    gains:
      RadTubePrismHorizontal:
        p: 200.0
        d: 60.0
        i: 0.01
        i_clamp: 1.0
      RadTubeLongitudinal:
        p: 200.0
        d: 60.0
        i: 0.01
        i_clamp: 1.0
      RadTubeLift:
        p: 200.0
        d: 60.0
        i: 0.01
        i_clamp: 1.0
      RadTubeRotVertical:
        p: 200.0
        d: 160.0
        i: 0.01
        i_clamp: 1.0
      RadTubeRotHorizontal:
        p: 100.0
        d: 50.0
        i: 0.01
        i_clamp: 1.0
      CollimatorRotA:
        p: 100.0
        d: 10.0
        i: 0.01
        i_clamp: 1.0


The error comes from the planned trajectory, not from the controller:
[gzserver-1] [ERROR] [1732573974.848351362] [robot_controller]: Time between points 0 and 1 is not strictly increasing, it is 0.000000 and 0.000000 respectively

Check your MoveIt settings (maybe there is no time parameterization of your path?).

I do not have "time parameterization" set in any configuration files or launch files. But I am also not sure how to set it up, I looked into it and it always seems like it has to deal with c++ nodes, can it just be set through the configuration files of moveit or the launch file of the simulation?
